# How to suppress “warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size”?

Tags: c, casting, suppress-warnings

**TL;DR:**

I need to do the following in my code (greatly simplified example):

```
int ret = 42;
void * marshaled_ret = (void *) ret;
int unmarshaled_ret = (int) marshaled_ret;
```

This results in the compiler warning:

> warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

**How can I suppress the compiler warning for this particular occurrence?**

---

Background: I am writing an abstraction layer around platform-specific multithreading libraries.

One big challenge is that the libraries expect different signatures for the thread’s main function. POSIX has

```
(void *)(*thread_main)(void *)
```

while Windows (effectively) has

```
int (*thread_main)(void *)
```

i.e. only the return type differs.

Since I need to have one function signature for all platforms, I went for `int` as the most constrained return type. When creating a thread, I marshal the user-supplied function and its parameter into a `struct` and call a wrapper function (which has the signature expected by the platform), which then calls the actual main function.

On POSIX, however, this involves casting `int` to `void *` and back, as shown above, which results in the compiler warning.

Obviously, casting an `int` to a pointer in this manner is a bad idea if you are using it as a pointer (segfaults are almost guaranteed). In this case, however, the pointer type is just my “integer mule”, never intended to be used as a pointer.

**How can I suppress the compiler warning for this particular occurrence?**

Comment: Use `uintptr_t` as an intermediate cast. But you will have a trouble if your `int` will go off the bounds of it.

Comment: "i.e. only the return type differs." - the return type and the number of bytes between pointer and `int` can also vary. (x64 8-byte pointer, 4-byte `int`)

Comment: Make `ret` a void pointer? `void *ret = (void *)42;
void * marshaled_ret = ret;`

Comment: That's the cleanest option, but for heaven's sake, never try and actually use `ret` as a pointer, code execution will likely come to a screeching halt as an address of 42 will be way down in the system protected memory range...

Comment: Side-note: Rather than going for the most constrained return type, your library could always provide the POSIX feature set by using a wrapper on Windows that smuggles in two `void*`s to the thread, one the thread's real argument, the other the threads return value. The thread create function allocates the return space and packs the argument and return address up, the wrapper unpacks, calls the "real" entry point with one, and sets the other to the return value. When the thread is joined, you pull out the returned value. Adds a little overhead on Windows, but can be zero overhead on pthreads.

Comment: Turns out someone already had the same idea (not really surprised): [Complete implementation of the pthreads interface using Windows' native threading API](https://locklessinc.com/articles/pthreads_on_windows/). Looks like [C11 threads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread) went with your approach though, making `thrd_start_t` a typedef for `int(*)(void*)`.

Comment: Count your blessings that you are getting this warning since it’s actually a big fat bug in your code. The roundtrip is simply not safe, because an `int` cannot represent your pointer value. As David said above, you mustn’t try using the pointer. But even *assignment* is (I think) not legal because the integer (which has been truncated) might not even contain a valid pointer value any more.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It looks like you misunderstood what I am trying to achieve. The conversion is `int` → `void *` → `int`, and semantically it is just an arbitrary number, not an address. Unless `int` is longer than a pointer on that particular platform, truncation is not an issue.

Comment: @user149408 It seems that I indeed misunderstood (I thought it was exactly the other way round) but this is still probably problematic because, as far as I know, you are not allowed to interpret random numbers as pointers (although, as far as I know, no mainstream platform actually forbids this, and plenty of existing pthread code exploits this).

Comment: Rather than trying to suppress the compiler warnings, simply always use the POSIX functions for threads

Answer (score 2):

When doing both conversions (`int` -> `void*` and `void*` -> `int`), cast to `uintptr_t` first, and then to the desired type:

```
int ret = 42;
void *marshaled_return = (void *)(uintptr_t)ret;
int unmarshaled_return = (int)(uintptr_t)marshaled_return;
```

Comment: Problem is `ret` is not a pointer and could have a different typesize. Why not `void *marshaled_return = &ret;` and then `int unmarshaled_return = *((int)marshaled_return);`? (unless it was declared local)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, seems he wants to hard-code an address

Comment: Yes, that was a bit confusing, but if that's the goal, then assigning that address with intermediate `uniptr` would be an option ... but that is more a baindaid than a solution pointing to a larger design problem.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I assume you meant `*((int*)marshaled_return);`, not `*((int)marshaled_return);`.

Comment: The issue is that OP is performing the opposite conversion first, i.e. the actual conversion chain is `void*` → `int` → `uintptr_t` → `void*`, and the first step in this chain contains a truncation which might subsequently result in an invalid pointer value. I *think* (but I don’t know) that this can lead to a hardware trap on some platforms, even if the pointer is never dereferenced.

Comment: To clarify: I do not ever intend to use that `void *` as a pointer to anything. `&ret` will not work because the address may no longer be valid by the time I read from it. Also, the conversion is `int` → `void *` → `int`, nothing meaningful to truncate.